# Trying to add a filter condition to TransferSpreadsheet using DAO and Me.filter

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007, dao

There is a button on a report that exports the underlying query of the report to excel. This function works fine as it would but I need it to take the criteria of the report. I have a massive reporting manager that will set the criteria for the report and then will open it up.

To make it easy, I want to pass `me.filter` to a variable which works in a different sub, but here my problem is that I need to pass the filter to be properly formatted for an sql statement I assume? The other sub just uses it as a [WhereCondition] for an open report command.

For clarification, the portion getreportsource() is a module that gets the reports source and it works fine. 
Here are some example outputs of the variables as well as the code:

strRptName: TotalSalesForYear

strRptSource: qryMainDashboard

FilterCondition: TxnDate >= #11/1/2017# AND TxnDate <= #11/30/2017#

```vb
Private Sub cmdExcel_Click()

Dim strRptName As String
Dim strRptSource As String
Dim vardate As String
Dim varExportPath As String
Dim FilterCondition As String
Dim oExcel

FilterCondition = Me.filter

' Get the Report Name
strRptName = Screen.ActiveReport.Name

' Get the RecordSource of the Report from a module
strRptSource = GetReportSource(strRptName)

'Present Date
vardate = Format$(Now(), "YYYY.MM.DD_HH-mm-ss")
'Path of export
varExportPath = "C:\Users\Public\Downloads\"

'Check for terminating backslash ExportLinkReportsOut filepath.
    If Right(varExportPath, 1) <> "\" Then
       varExportPath = varExportPath & "\"
    End If
    varExportPath = varExportPath & strRptName & ".xlsx"

' set dao and create temp table
Dim cdb As DAO.Database, qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Const tempTableName = "_tempTbl"
Set cdb = CurrentDb

'deletes temp table and handles error
On Error Resume Next
DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, tempTableName
On Error GoTo 0

Set qdf = cdb.CreateQueryDef("")
qdf.SQL = "SELECT * INTO [" & tempTableName & "] FROM [" & strRptSource & "] where filtercondition"
qdf.Execute
Set qdf = Nothing
Set cdb = Nothing

' export spreadsheet with the temp table, the export path, and then open the spreadsheet
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, , tempTableName, varExportPath, True
Set oExcel = GetObject(varExportPath)
oExcel.Application.Visible = True
oExcel.Parent.Windows(1).Visible = True


End Sub
```

Everything works when I change `qdf.SQL = "SELECT * INTO [" & tempTableName & "] FROM [" & strRptSource & "] where filtercondition"` to `qdf.SQL = "SELECT * INTO [" & tempTableName & "] FROM [" & strRptSource & "] "`

Problem is there is no filter when I drop filtercondition, obviously. 
The error I keep getting is "Run-time error '3061': Too few paramters. Expected 1."

Anyone have any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you aren't concatenating the filter condition. Your query just states `WHERE filtercondition`, not `WHERE TxnDate >= #11/1/2017# AND TxnDate <= #11/30/2017#`

Change `qdf.SQL = "SELECT * INTO [" & tempTableName & "] FROM [" & strRptSource & "] where filtercondition"` to `qdf.SQL = "SELECT * INTO [" & tempTableName & "] FROM [" & strRptSource & "] WHERE " & filtercondition`

Comment: Concatenating is my mortal enemy. I changed your code in order to fix the concatenation in it ... WHERE ' & filtercondition'   Problem now is that it will still only export the whole query rather than what was set in the qdf.sql as if there was no filter. Any idea why?

Comment: That's not what I shared. Those quotes are relevant. Please be explicit about your quotes, and copy exactly what I proposed

Comment: Yes it was a dumb error on my part. Thanks for you input and your time.